# Noncommutative boolean ring based on ℤ3

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am working with the book "Abstract Algebra - Theory and Applications" by Thomas W. Judson. On page 205 it lists the following exercise: "A ring R is a Boolean ring if for every $a ∈ R, a^2 = a$. Show that every Boolean ring is a commutative ring.".

Trying to work on this exercise, I came up with the non-commutative ring based on group ℤ$_3$, which is fully defined by the following addition and multiplication tables:

Addition (≅ ℤ$_3$) :
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
+& 0 & a & b \\ \hline
0 & 0 & a & b \\ \hline
a & a & b & 0 \\ \hline
b & b & 0 & a \\ \hline
\end{array}
Multiplication:
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
*& 0 & a & b \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
a & 0 & a & b \\ \hline
b & 0 & a & b \\ \hline
\end{array}
This ring meets all the conditions needed for a ring to be classified as such (abelian additive group, multiplication closure and associativity, distributive axiom). It also satisfies the condition for Boolean rings ($∀x∈R, x^2 = x$). However it is non-commutative ($ab ≠ ba$).

Upon closer inspection I discovered that the boolean ring condition $∀x∈R, x^2 = x$ leads to $a + a = a + a + a + a$. Consulting the addition table we see that $a + a = b$. Thus the equation $a + a = a + a + a + a$ becomes $b = b + b$ and then $0 = b$.
This is rather surprising to me. I started with what I considered non-commutative ring based on ℤ$_3$ and ended up with symbol "b" in my group being equivalent to additive 0. If the symbol "b" is equivalent to 0, then my original addition and multiplication tables collapse into 2x2 versions of boolean ring based on ℤ$_2$ group.

Was my original ring definition based on ℤ$_3$ somehow flawed? It does meet all the conditions that rings are supposed to meet, doesn't it? It also meets the condition for boolean rings, right?.
If so, then what went wrong that caused my ring to collapse into its smaller version based on ℤ$_2$ group? Is this really a non-commutative boolean ring?

Comment: I do not see an element "$1$" that has $1\cdot a=a\cdot1$ for all $a$.
(Actually I also don't see the tables correctly, but it seems you did use the proper table format in your post! Something wrong with MathJax?)

Comment: OP probably wants to construct a "rng" (without unity). Alas, distributivity actually doesn't hold here: consider $(a+b)a$.

Comment: @Amateur_Algebraist You are correct. Distributivity doesn't hold here. My fault. I thoroughly checked only the forward direction a(a+b) and forgot about the other one (a+b)a. This is not a ring then. Thank you for your help.